# Live Streaming from Raspberrypi using WebRTC

Tags: raspberry-pi, webrtc, kurento, janus, uv4l

I want to have a server which will have live stream from the raspberrypi's.
I am expecting a low latency live stream from Raspberrypi with the help of WebRTC.
If there is any way I can achieve this flow please let me know the steps involved in this process.
I tried a flow with Janus and UV4L, the server is also already up but I am facing the following error

```
Creating new session: 8369675473992662; 0x7f69ac001320
Creating new handle in session 8369675473992662: 3129073299361989; 0x7f69ac001320 0x7f69ac001ab0
[ERR] [plugins/janus_videoroom.c:janus_videoroom_process_synchronous_request:3013] Room 1234 already exists!
[3129073299361989] Creating ICE agent (ICE Full mode, controlled)
[WARN] [3129073299361989] ICE failed for component 1 in stream 1, but we're still waiting for some info so we don't care... (trickle pending, answer received, alert not set)
[ERR] [ice.c:janus_ice_check_failed:1760] [3129073299361989] ICE failed for component 1 in stream 1...
[janus.plugin.videoroom-0x7f69980126a0] No WebRTC media anymore; 0x7f69ac001ab0 0x7f69ac002080
[3129073299361989] WebRTC resources freed; 0x7f69ac001ab0 0x7f69ac001320
```

Any help is appreciated, if there is any other way apart from Janus, please let me know about it